# Bufferreader and Bufferwriter for reading and writing hdfs files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to read from a hdfs file line by line and then create a hdfs file and write to it line by line. The code that I use looks like this:

```
            Path FileToRead=new Path(inputPath);
        FileSystem hdfs = FileToRead.getFileSystem(new Configuration());            
        FSDataInputStream fis = hdfs.open(FileToRead);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String line;
            line = reader.readLine(); 
            while (line != null){

                String[] lineElem = line.split(",");
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

                    MyMatrix[i][Integer.valueOf(lineElem[0])-1] = Double.valueOf(lineElem[i+1]);
                }

                line=reader.readLine();
        } 

        reader.close();
        fis.close();


        Path FileToWrite = new Path(outputPath+"/V"); 
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(FileToWrite);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut));
        writer.write("check");
        writer.close();
        fileOut.close();
```

When I run this code in my outputPath file V has not been created. But if I replace the part for reading with the part for writing the file will be created and check is written into it. 
Can anyone please help me understand how to use them correctly to be able to read first the whole file and then write to the file line by line?

I have also tried another code for reading from one file and writing to another one but the file will be created but there is nothing written into it!

I use sth like this:

```
  hadoop jar main.jar program2.Main input output
```

Then in my first job I read from arg[0] and write to a file in args[1]+"/NewV"  using map reduce classes and it works. 
In my other class (non map reduce)I use args[1]+"/NewV" as input path and output+"/V_0" as output path (I pass these strings to constructor). here is the code for the class :

```
 public class Init_V {

String inputPath, outputPath;


public Init_V(String inputPath, String outputPath) throws Exception {

    this.inputPath = inputPath;
    this.outputPath = outputPath;


    try{            

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        Path FileToWrite = new Path(outputPath+"/V.txt"); 
        Path FileToRead=new Path(inputPath);
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter
         (new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(FileToWrite,
                 true)));  

        BufferedReader reader = new
            BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(FileToRead)));
                 String data;
                 data = reader.readLine();
                 while ( data != null ) 
                 {
                     output.write(data);
                     data = reader.readLine();
                 }
                 reader.close();                     
                 output.close(); }catch(Exception e){
}

}

}
```

Comment: Does the file exist on the local path? It may be that either you're passing the output path with a local context (`file:///path/to/file`), or the default file system is local. Can you share the invocation line you're launching the program with, and the value of `fs.default.name` from your `$HADOOP_CONF/core-site.xml`

Comment: Actually the file that I'm trying to read is a file that is created by another job in HDFS. And it exists in the output directory that is located in HDFS. After reading this file I can create the file that I want to write into in the same directory output(in HDFS). I use "hadoop fs -get output output" in order to copy it to my local machine and when I check the newly created file, it is empty!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to understand how hadoop works properly. In hadoop, many thing is done by the system, you are just giving input and output path, then they are opened and created by hadoop if the paths are valid. Check the following example;

```
public int run (String[] args) throws Exception{

    if(args.length != 3){
        System.err.println("Usage: MapReduce <input path> <output path> ");
        ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
    }
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(MyClass.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(5);
    job.setJobName("myclass");
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]) );
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1 ;
}


/* ----------------------main---------------------*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    

    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MyClass(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

As you see here, you only initialize necessary variables and reading&writing is done by hadoop.

Also, in your **Mapper class** you are saying `context.write(key, value)` inside map, and similarly in your **Reduce class** you are doing same, it writes for you.

If you use BufferedWriter/Reader it will write to your local file system not to HDFS. To see files in HDFS you should write `hadoop fs -ls <path>`, the files you are looking by `ls` command are in your local file system

**EDIT:** In order to use read/write you should know the followings: Let say you have N machine in your hadoop network. When you want to read, you will not know which mapper is reading, similarly writing. So, all mappers and reducer should have those paths not to give exception.

I dont know if you could use any other class but you can use two methods for your specific reason: `startup` and `cleanup`. These methods are used only once in each map and reduce worker. So if you want to read and write you can use that files. Reading and writing is same as normal java code. For example, you want to see something for each key, and want to write it to a txt. You can do the following:

```
//in reducer
BufferedReader bw ..;

void startup(...){
     bw  = new ....;
}

void reduce(...){
    while(iter.hasNext()){ ....;
    }
    bw.write(key, ...);
}
void cleanup(...){
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is that I want to work with hdfs files in a class but not necessarily map or reduce classes. In the second code the output file is created in hdfs but there is noting written into it! Is there any way to read and write hdfs files in a class but map or reduce?

Comment: the working style of hadoop is `for each key(generally line)` do `map` operation and `for each key in reducer collect elements of the same key and write in to hdfs`. I dont know if there is another way of using map reduce, but by this way you are automatically sorting data according to key. this is another advantage of MR.

Comment: I guess I'm not asking my question correctly. Actually I'm trying to read from the file and write to the file not using Mapper or Reduce classes. I need to read from a file once and store the data (I use matrix) and after processing the data write the result in another file. But I want to do all of this in an ordinary class, not Mapper or Reduce. I have to work with one file and want to have access to all of the lines at the same time and I'm not sure if using the distributedcache will solve my problem. If I want to use Mapper and Reduce I might need 2 jobs which will take quite long.

Comment: I have editted my post. read only after EDIT, which is supposed to be ur answer if i understand correctly

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But I'm afraid this won't help either. Let me explain what type of problem I'm trying to solve. Maybe it becomes more clear. I have a file which contains IDs and feature vectors (each line looks like this: ID,1,3,4). I need to read line by line and calculate the distance for that ID to the other lines and find the minimum distance for each. Then I should find K max distances among these minimums and write the IDs and feature vectors with max (min distance) into another text file. I want my input and output to be in HDFS and not local.

Comment: I didn't know how to do it with Mapper and Reduce. I can find minimums and write them to one file but for k Max have no idea. And the mapper reads one line, but I need to have access to all lines. And for finding k max I need to have access to all minimums. I know how to do it in an ordinary class. So if I can solve the problem of reading and writing HDFS files, the problem can be solved!

Comment: Do u mean all lines starting with ID or all lines in the file? If it is each ID, then, your key is gonna be ID, and reduce is gonna collect all the lines corresponding to the ID and you will do what ever you want at the end of reduce method. If you mean all lines, then you dont have to work on hadoop, because it is not helping you at all.

Comment: Yes I mean all the lines with different IDs. Actually this is a small part that I'm not gonna use Mapper and Reduce. I need them for the rest of my program.

Comment: You can collect all data related to an ID in reducer. at the very end of reducer you would call a method, let say, `Id_issue()` this method will do whatever you want.